# Adding nuget package to c# project on PC without internet

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Im working on PC that connect to internal network (not internet)
I tried to add external nuget package to my visual studio solution but i got that error when i tried to install it; 
Unable to load the service index for soruce https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/.
Need some help 
Thank you

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of a question I answered recently: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53705220/2843065. If this answer doesn't help, please provide more information why.

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding nuget package to c# project on PC without internet

The easiest way is that download nuget packages on your internet connected computer, then create a local feed for those packages on the PC without internet, so that you can see those packages in the Manage Package for Solutions and add them to C# project on the PC without internet.

Details:

> - Add those packages .nupkg into your local repository folder.
> - Head into Visual Studio and open the NuGet Settings dialog via Tools    NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings. Click the
>     Package Sources tab within the settings dialog, followed by the plus
>     icon in    the top left to add a new package source.
> - Enter the Name and Source of your local repository. The name can be    any string and will be the name displayed in the NuGet Package
>     Manager within Visual Studio.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009642/installing-nuget-package-located-in-local-package-repository-into-a-new-visual-s) for how to create local feed.

Hope this helps