# Handling System package dependencies for packages in RestoreSources path

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild, nuget

I have a project where I have PackageReference field for few packages. I am trying to restore and build this project on a ubuntu system(basically a docker image) with no internet access.

I would like these packages to be found in a directory where I have pre-installed them and build to proceed.

I tried giving a RestoreSources path where the packages which are referred via PackageReference in the project are pre-installed. But when I do this, I start getting "error NU1101: Unable to find package..." error for System packages such as System.IO and System.Collections etc saying that these system packages are not found in the path which I specified in the RestoreSources path.

I am not sure why the build system is trying to find the system package in the path specified in the RestoreSources path instead of the .NET installation on the system ?

Comment: Not an answer, but this might be good enough ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028424/download-nuget-packages-for-offline-development-publishing