# Nuget.exe and NuGet Package Manager resolve different dependencies

Tags: c#, nuget, offline

I want to install `OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua` version `1.4.355.26` (and all of its dependencies) to an offline machine.  My online and offline machines are running `Visual Studio 2019 16.1.3`.

When I install `OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua` version `1.4.355.26` using the `NuGet Package Manager`, it installs many dependencies, including `Libuv.1.10.0`. See screenshot:

[image: NuGet Package Manager resolves Libuv.1.10.0]

When I download the same package for offline installation, `nuget.exe` fetches `Libuv.1.9.2`. See screenshot:

[image: nuget.exe resolves Libuv.1.9.2]

```
C:\Users\cstankevitz\Downloads>nuget.exe install OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua
Feeds used:
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

Installing package 'OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua' to 'C:\Users\cstankevitz\Downloads'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/opcfoundation.netstandard.opc.ua/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/opcfoundation.netstandard.opc.ua/index.json 558ms


Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua.1.4.355.26' with respect to project 'C:\Users\cstankevitz\Downloads', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Gathering dependency information took 16.89 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua.1.4.355.26' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua.1.4.355.26'
Resolved actions to install package 'OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua.1.4.355.26'
Retrieving package 'Libuv 1.9.2' from 'nuget.org'.
...
```

Of course, when I bring the downloaded packages to my offline machine and install them using `Visual Studio 2019 NuGet Package Manager`, the install fails because the `Libuv.1.10.0` is not available.

How can I get `nuget.exe` (or any other tool) to download the *correct* packages needed by `NuGet Package Manager` for offline installation?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I installed the correct dependencies to my offline system:

### On the online system

1. Fetch the source of https://github.com/StuffOfInterest/NuGetDependencyDownloader
2. Edit `PackageTools.cs` and modify the function `GetRangedPackageVersion` so that it contains the code below.  This is needed to fix a "bug" in which older packages are not downloaded when newer packages are available -- but the older packages will be needed in Step 9 below.
3. Compile and run `NuGetDependencyDownloader` to download the package and its dependencies
4. Copy the packages to an external drive

### On the offline system

5. Copy the packages to your offline system (`c:\Work\2019-07018 Nuget Offline\` in my example)
6. Edit options for `Nuget Package Manager | Package Sources`.  Add a source that points to the directory used in step 5.  [Specify Local Package Source Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8XZn.png)
7. Run `Nuget Package Manager`.
8. Specify the `Package source` that you created in step 6.  [Specify package source screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOEgS.png)
9. Install your package
10. Notice that it appears to install but nothing is actually happening.  It is trying to contact something online (which will fail after a long timeout).  This is repeated for every dependency.  Speed up the failure by disconnecting all of your interfaces (unplug cables, etc).

```
    private IPackage GetRangedPackageVersion(IQueryable<IPackage> packages, IVersionSpec versionSpec)
    {
      packages = packages.Where(o => o.Version == versionSpec.MinVersion);

      IPackage package = packages
          .OrderByDescending(o => o.Version)
          .FirstOrDefault();

      return package;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of the Preview Changes dialog in VS, all the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` packages are version 2.0.1, whereas running `nuget.exe`, it got versions 1.1.x. If you [look at `OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua` on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua/) and expand the dependencies, you see it has dependencies on the 1.1 packages for `net46` and `netstandard2.0`, but 2.0 dependencies for `netstandard2.0`.

From this I can deduce that your project is using `netcoreapp2.0`, `netstandard2.0`, or above, whereas `nuget.exe` is probably using some .NET Framework for dependencies.

As for ways to get the same packages that your project actually uses, I've answered this question several times in the past and I usually [link to the first time I answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568997/command-to-download-a-nuget-package-with-all-dependencies-to-a-folder/53572866#53572866)