# How to download all Nuget packages referenced in VS solution as nupkg files?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have Visual Studio 2017 solution with several Nuget packages referenced. I want build that solution on the computer not connected to the internet. So I will not able download Nuget packages. I want download all Nuget packages referenced in my solution as *.nupkg files and then specify local folder with these files as packges source (Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources).

I don't want download the packages manually, so number of ones is significant.

I aware about *<UserFolder>\.nuget\packages* folder, but that folder contains all packages ever downloaded for the all solutions. I need packages for specific solution only.

Comment: A simple hack here would be to rename the .nuget/packages folder to something else then restore the solution. Then copy the .nuget/packages folder to some other location and create a package source that points to copied folder.

Comment: Hi Matt, that is the good answer and l suggest you could add an answer for this issue and it will help lgor and other community members handle similar issues.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Renaming the package(just like [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders))folder is just to download only the nuget packages needed for the current solution in packages  folder because the default VS recovery packages are all downloaded into [the global cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`.

Comment: After that, you can copy the folder into the target PC,add the path into package source. By doing all of the above, you can successfully build your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is pretty much a duplicate of a question from a year ago, where [I posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572866/2843065) that is conceptually the same as what Matt Ward suggested. The difference is that instead of renaming your global packages folder, you use `nuget.config` to specify a different location.